# Abstract Factory violate Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

Tell me please, the **abstract factory** **violates** the principle of a **single responsibility** ? (I think that he has a lot of responsibility).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Abstract Factory has a single responsibility, providing a contract for the creation of polymorphic objects without binding the interface to a specific implementation.  In other words the contract is its responsibility not making the objects.

The SRP applies to each class, the Abstract Factory is only one class in the pattern, each Concrete factory has different but similar responsibility.  Do not think of a responsibility as a single function, it could be a compound.

Answer (score 0):

When counting responsibilities, the "trick" is to figure out what makes up a responsibility. When you think about "number of object creations", a complex factory can perform quite a few tasks. But even when the result is a fairly complex object graph, the 1 responsibility of the factory is to create that graph.

A monstrous sequence of steps may be broken up into parts and sub-components to make testing easier, for example, but in the end someone has to call the initializer/constructor with whatever arguments and dependencies it takes to set it up. That's the responsibility of the factory itself.